# How do add column with value derived from other column?

Tags: sqlite

There are three fields in the table `quote` with columns `code`, `name`, `close`.
I want to create a 4th field `type`:

```
if close>10 , type=m else close<=10 , type=n
```

What SQL statement would I have to use in SQLite?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Sj The title is misleading; it is not descriptive of the question.  You want to create a new column and a trigger, I think.  May I edit the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update that column with a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```
ALTER TABLE quote ADD COLUMN type TEXT;
UPDATE quote SET type = CASE WHEN close > 10 THEN 'm' ELSE 'n' END;
```